# What are these No beacon, Next in ... log messages in Chrome developer console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

All of a sudden I started getting these messages in my Google Chrome developer console. I think I accidentally enabled something.

```
VM81:1 No beacon 52501
VM81:1 Next in ... 24000
VM81:1 No beacon 53776
VM81:1 Next in ... 48000
VM81:1 No beacon 57503
VM81:1 Next in ... 96000
VM81:1 No beacon 64503
VM81:1 Next in ... 192000
VM81:1 No beacon 77778
VM81:1 Next in ... 384000
```

[image: Chrome Developer Console Log]

How do I disable this?! It doesn't happen when I visit the server on other machines.
The logs are coming from `debugger:///VM81`.

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-F (devtools menu -> more tools -> search) and search for "No beacon".

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this same problem for days!! I finally tracked down the issue as being a part of the Hover Zoom Chrome extension.

Try disabling the extension, I hope this fixes it for you as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a life saver.